# can't get php preg_repace to work over more lines on xhtml-code

Tags: php, html, xhtml, preg-replace

I am trying to write a script that replaces some html tags into other or more html tags.
Choose preg_replace because of the nice effect with variables in it.
For Example:

```
$xhtmlcode = preg_replace('@<h(.*?)>(.*?)</h(.*?)>@is','<h$1><sub>$2</sub></h$3>', $xhtmlinput);
```

This above code works and gives me an expecting result, but then after it i do a:

```
$xhtmlcode = preg_replace('@<li(.*?)>(.*?)</li>@is','<li><sub>$2</sub></li>', $xhtminput);
```

just pays NULL as output..

The same thing happens when work with other code like this, 
now I realy like to know why this happens:

```
  $xhthmlintput = '
  <span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:12.5px">this is the test world</span>
  <span style="font-size:5.5px">this is the test planet</span>
  <span style="font-size:5.5px">test it well</span>';
```

AND i got the same problem again with:

```
$xhtmlcode = preg_replace( '@<span style="(.*?)bold(.*?)>(.*?)</span>@i', '<b>$3</b>', $xhtmlintput );
```

I get troubles again with a NULL as output again.

Comment: show us some example content, what you want to replace, with what...

Comment: You obtain NULL because there is no 2nd capture group. You need to use `$1` instead of `$2`. But you will better do this with DOMDocument.

Comment: You where right Casimir, I posted the wrong code there, just edited the right one.

Comment: [Don't use regex to modifiy HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)! Use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath` instead

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS to change what H1, H2, LI, etc. look like?

Comment: thank you for the DOMDocument idea it works great for a lot of stuff, but still why is this code up here nog doing its regex thing?

Comment: @scher200 you get null due to typo - you wrote `$xhtmlintput` instead of `$xthmlintput`

Comment: thanks you Cheery, but sadly it is still giving me NULL